# Display Error Message 8618 when executing T-SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem in T-SQL Code.
I have two views in SQL Server that I want to get their values using the inner join function.
Both my views displays the information separately.
But when I want to join them, I get this error.
error shown when I add a field from the second view.
this is error:

> Msg 8618, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required is a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size of the fields in the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash (CHECKSUM()) of fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note however that this will change the behavior of the query.

The code I tried is as follows.

```
SELECT a.idaccount,
       a.accountname,
       a.dates,
       a.idcurrencyaccount,
       a.accountcurrname,
       a.accountdescription,
       a.factordescription,
       a.quantityaqlam,
       a.nobsabt,
       a.pricebedehkary,
       b.pricetalab
FROM   view_Finance_Report_Summary_BedehkaryandPaid AS a
       INNER JOIN view_Finance_Summary_TalabatandReceived AS b
               ON a.idaccount = b.idaccount
```

Note: I even reduced the number of fields but it didn't make a difference.
An error occurs only when I add a field from the view_Finance_Summary_TalabatandReceived view that is b.PriceTalab field.

Comment: Do you have some group/order/partition by in the views? you probably need to simplify your view code

Comment: Since both of these views have "summary" in their names can we safely assume that they are doing some kind of grouping and aggregating? Are you able to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76751627/edit) your question to include the view definitions and the DDL of the table(s) that they reference?

Comment: Please show the definitions of these views.